# QEMU parts of screen is cut off in window mode

Tags: sonoma

I'm trying to test some Hello world level bootloader in QEMU. (Bootloader is working fine and I can see the `H` character I try to print when I put qemu to fullscreen, or move it to `0x190` instead of `0x0`)

How do I get the QEMU to display properly? without cutting off some rows.
[image: qemu-does-not-show-0_0]

Comment: I'm thinking I need to tweak some window settings :(

Comment: hmm this seems like a bug - https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/1994